# Meu executável ainda está numa versão antiga

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic-6, compilação

Compilo o projeto do VB e quando abro a pasta para pegar o exe gerado, ainda está com data antiga, que nesse caso é de 18/03/2017 e não 20/04/2017. Tem alguma coisa que eu devo fazer? Eu compilo assim: Ctrl+F5 e depois abro a pasta onde está o projeto. Tem outra forma? Posso estar enganado, mas em Delphi, por exemplo, posso ter os fontes em uma pasta e gerar o exe em outra. Acho que VB também, mas eu não sei como fazer isso.

> Obs: Para algumas pessoas, tenho usado a tag visual-studio, pois ela
>   compila o VB(depende da versão) e a pergunta tem a ver com compilação,
>   geração de exe e isso é devidamente configurada na IDE.

Comment: Você não está compilando apenas executando um "Start With Full Compile".

Comment: No Visual Studio a configuração de versão das assemblies faz parte do código fonte do projeto que vai ser compilado, portanto não tem a ver com a IDE. Se você compilar via linha de comando vai ter as mesmas características de versão.

Comment: O que eu acho provável no seu caso é que entre a IDE e o compilador, um dos dois decidiu que seu código fonte que gera o EXE não teve alterações significativas entre as datas no post. Daí o compilador não gera um novo executável. Acho que se você modificar alguma instrução, deve ver o compilador gerar um novo executável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para compilar acesse o menu File > Make